# Besides Blue, were there any other raptors that survived?

Tags: jurassic-world

In the ending of *Jurassic World* we see Blue running in the direction that Echo or Delta was tossed in by the I-Rex, as Blue had answered a raptor call.

I think Delta was burned to death. But were there any others from the four raptors besides Blue that survived the events.

Comment: Apparently not ... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94306/which-raptor-survived

Comment: in the next flim the trailer shows Blue calling help but it possible scared about the volcano explosion